# Merge two tuples into one

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, tuples

I have two tuples

```
("string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6","string7")
```

and

```
("another string1","another string2",3,None,"another string5",6,7)
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
("string1another string1","string2another string2","string33","string4","string5another string5","string66","string77").
```

It would also be ok with a result like:

```
("string1another string1","string2another string2","string33","string4None","string5another string5","string66","string77")
```

But since I'm new to Python I'm not sure on how do that. What is the best way of combining the two tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip` and a generator expression:

```
>>> t1=("string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6","string7")
>>> t2=("another string1","another string2",3,None,"another string5",6,7)
```

First expected output:

```
>>> tuple("{0}{1}".format(x if x is not None else "" ,
                             y if y is not None else "") for x,y in zip(t1,t2))
('string1another string1', 'string2another string2', 'string33', 'string4', 'string5another string5', 'string66', 'string77')
```

Second expected output:

```
>>> tuple("{0}{1}".format(x,y) for x,y in zip(t1,t2)) #tuple comverts LC to tuple
('string1another string1', 'string2another string2', 'string33', 'string4None', 'string5another string5', 'string66', 'string77')
```

Use this [ternary expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to handle the `None` values:

```
>>> x = "foo"
>>> x if x is not None else ""
'foo'
>>> x = None
>>> x if x is not None else ""
''
```

Comment: +1, but… why are you passing a listcomp to `tuple` instead of a generator expression? It makes it slightly harder to read (more parens/brackets/etc. to keep track of), and wastes memory in large cases, and the 2.x performance benefit in tiny cases is almost never going to matter.

Comment: @abarnert you got it right, performance is the only reason I sometimes prefer list comprehension instead of generator expression. It's a bad habit that I've picked up from programming competitions where performance matters.

Comment: Couldn't it be: x if x else "" ?

Comment: @dansalmo: That depends on the use case. Skipping `''` vs. printing `''` obviously makes no difference either way, but if you get, say, `0`, or `False`, or `[]`, do you want to skip those too?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: "Performance matters" is one thing; "Guessing the kinds of data they'll give me so I know whether or not to write code that's 3% faster on small inputs but 300% slower on big inputs" seems like it's testing something other than programming. (Although still something you'll need to be good at in the real world, especially if you ever work with "business analysts"!)

Comment: What happens if t1 and t2 don't have the same amount of elements?
In my case that is a programing error but still would be nice to know incase of future use.

Comment: @Mattias zip runs only runs up to the shorter of the two, for unequal tuples you can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

Answer (score 1):

Try zip function like

```
>>> a = ("string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6","string7")
>>> b = ("another string1","another string2",3,None,"another string5",6,7)
>>> [str(x)+str(y) for x,y in zip(a,b)]
['string1another string1', 'string2another string2', 'string33', 'string4None', 'string5another string5', 'string66', 'string77']
```

If you want the result be tuple, you could do like:

```
>>> tuple([str(x)+str(y) for x,y in zip(a,b)])
('string1another string1', 'string2another string2', 'string33', 'string4None', 'string5another string5', 'string66', 'string77')
```

Comment: This is almost right, but `"string4" + None` is a `TypeError`, not `"string4None"`. (And if you fix that, how is this different from Ashwini Chaudhary's earlier answer?)

Comment: @abarnert The askers said "string4None" is OK. And I used the str() function before joining two parts. So it should work well.